# Upload image to rails throwing incompatible character encodings UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

I know that similar questions has made about this problem, but I can't force filename convertion inside ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile. And seems not correct doing this way.

I'm uploading a file with [Jquery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/), sending to rails and saving with Paperclip

This is my parameters in rails controller:
Note the **@original_filename="ééééááá.jpg"** to **filename=\"\xC3\xA9\xC3\xA9\xC3....**

```
 Parameters: {"files"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe7d587d5d8 @original_filename="ééééááá.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files[]\"; filename=\"\xC3\xA9\xC3\xA9\xC3\xA9\xC3\xA9\xC3\xA1\xC3\xA1\xC3\xA1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/xn/tp46f9fn0kz1181k28c45zf40000gn/T/RackMultipart20120710-65737-1ac40o4>>], "id"=>"1"}
```

> Encoding::CompatibilityError (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8
>   and ASCII-8BIT):   app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:21:in
>   `create'

I have to solve this at server-side or client/form side?

**UPDATED**

Well, I checked https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/301 and solved this doing:

```
AWS.config( :logger => nil )
```

But still too monkey, cause the resize still throwing utf8 exception

**UPDATED 2**

Moved to carrierwave instead